# How to create a new array of consecutive elements without leaving the last element out?

Tags: python

How do I create an array of consecutive words (1st position of the tuple elements) without leaving the last element out.

For example I have a sample array

```
sample_array = [('do', 61), ('hello', 61), ('me', 61), ('me', 324), ('now', 61), ('now', 324), ('text', 3), ('you', 61), ('you', 3)]
```

Since there are 3 consecutive words, namely, 'me', 'now' and 'you', I want to output 3 arrays.

```py
[('me', 61), ('me', 324)]
[('now', 61), ('now', 324)]
[('you', 61), ('you', 3)]
```

Here's my current code:

```py
output = []
for i in range(len(sample_array) -1):
    if sample_array[i][0] == sample_array[i+1][0]:
        output.append(sample_array[i])
    else:
        if output != []:
            output.append(sample_array[i])
            print(output)
            output = []
```

But its output is

```py
[('me', 61), ('me', 324)]
[('now', 61), ('now', 324)]
```

How do I include the elements with the word 'you'?

Comment: but then there'll be an error since when i reaches the last iteration, sample_array[i+1] does not exist @Derlin

Comment: What is the expected output in the case of `sample_array = [('do', 61), ('do', 21), ('do', 11)]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One easy solution would be to add a *dummy* item at the end of the list:

```
def print_consecutive(sample_array_orig):
    output = []
    # add a dummy item at the end, that won't conflict with your data
    sample_array = sample_array_orig + [(None, None)] 
    # then just use your code
    for i in range(len(sample_array)-1):
        if sample_array[i][0] == sample_array[i + 1][0]:
            output.append(sample_array[i])
        else:
            if output != []:
                output.append(sample_array[i])
                print(output)
                output = []

print_consecutive(sample_array)
```

an easier way would be to use existing tools, such as `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
for key, group in groupby(sample_array, key=lambda t: t[0]):
    group = list(group)
    if len(group) > 1:
        print(group)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one solution without `itertools` and manual grouping by a key:

```py
sample_array = [('do', 61), ('hello', 61), ('me', 61), ('me', 324), ('now', 61), ('now', 324), ('text', 3), ('you', 61), ('you', 3)]

result_dict = {}
for k, v in sample_array:
    result_dict.setdefault(k, []).append((k, v))

result = list(filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1, result_dict.values()))

for row in result:
    print(row)
```

The output is:

```py
[('me', 61), ('me', 324)]
[('now', 61), ('now', 324)]
[('you', 61), ('you', 3)]
```

Comment: This won't ensure the keys are *consecutive*. If you append a `(do, 0)` at the end, it will be printed as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it using generators, which can be useful if you have large data.

First, we group the tuples having the same first item using `groupby`, then we filter the groups, keeping only the groups containing more than one item.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

sample_array = [('do', 61), ('hello', 61), ('me', 61), ('me', 324), ('now', 61), ('now', 324), ('text', 3), ('you', 61), ('you', 3)]

groups = (list(group) for key, group in groupby(sample_array, itemgetter(0)))
out = (group for group in groups if len(group) > 1)

print(list(out))


#[[('me', 61), ('me', 324)], [('now', 61), ('now', 324)], [('you', 61), ('you', 3)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

It can't get simpler than that:

```
sample_array = [('do', 61), ('hello', 61), ('me', 61), ('me', 324), ('now', 61), ('now', 324), ('text', 3), ('you', 61), ('you', 3)]

result = []
for i, item in enumerate(sample_array):
    try:
        if item[0] == sample_array[i+1][0]:
            result.append([item, sample_array[i+1]])
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

If you check `result`:

```
for item in result:
    print(item)

[('me', 61), ('me', 324)]
[('now', 61), ('now', 324)]
[('you', 61), ('you', 3)]
```

To answer @Derlin comment, here a slightly more complex version that can handle more than 2 consecutive entries.

```
sample_array = [('do', 61), ('hello', 61), ('me', 61), ('me', 324), ('me', 666), ('now', 61), ('now', 324), ('text', 3), ('you', 61), ('you', 3)]

result = []
tmp = set()
for i, item in enumerate(sample_array):
    try:
        if item[0] == sample_array[i+1][0]:
            tmp.add(item)
            tmp.add(sample_array[i+1])
        else:
            if len(tmp):
                result.append(tmp)
            tmp = set()  
    except IndexError:
        if len(tmp):
            result.append(tmp)



for item in result:
    print(item)

{('me', 666), ('me', 61), ('me', 324)}
{('now', 324), ('now', 61)}
{('you', 3), ('you', 61)}
```

Comment: Will fail on something as easy as `sample_array = [('do', 61), ('do', 21), ('do', 11)]`.

Comment: @Derlin Why do you think it fails? It outputs `[[('do', 61), ('do', 21)], [('do', 21), ('do', 11)]]` isn't correct? The OP didn't specify how many consecutive words.

Comment: *an array of consecutive words* is not the same as *arrays of tuple of consecutive words*, I am just applying Occam's razor ^^'

Comment: Good point, I have asked the OP to clarify on that. I will change my answer in that case.